# Ring oscillater for measuring the threshold voltage variation

Tags: oscillator

[image]

I have to write a paper about a threshold voltage variability detector using a ring oscillator.

I have a circuit like pictured above, and I have to write some things about how to test it; basically:

- What instruments I would use
- What type of measurements I would do and
- Some conclusion.

I'm not sure what to write because I'm not sure also what the other modules from the picture are supposed to do. If you could help me with that I would appreciate it.

Comment: so, you're supposed to write a report, but you don't know what a capacitor does?

Comment: And I'm not quite sure what threshold voltages. Are we talking about EEPROMs? CCDs? CMOS camera sensors? A lot of things have thresholds...

Comment: It doesnt really matter what threshold voltage..It can be a sensor or even a simple transistor. The main idea of the paper is that I can use just a ring oscillator to detect some voltage variation. My area of interest is how can i test the circuit? What lab instruments I should use? What should I put at the input of the circuit? What should I check at the output?

Comment: George, you ask us to explain this block diagram. When asked what the block diagram actually represents, you deflect – um, how do you expect us to help, then?

Comment: This diagram is a testbench example for the testing the ring oscillator. I wanna know how I should handle this testbench in a laboratory..What instruments I should use and whats the testing method?